# How to set variables in base template in django?

Tags: django, templates

i have template base.html and some children templates. I don't know how to set variables for base.html

for example if i have `{% for u in users %}{% endfor %}` where do I assign it to users? is there some parent view for all views?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want certain variables to be available in all templates, you could write a [template context processor](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/jun/14/django-tips-template-context-processors/) ([docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors)) and make sure you always use [`RequestContext`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#id1) when rendering templates.

Answer (score 0):

You don't assign variables separately to parent templates. A template extends a parent template, and the whole thing just has one context for variables.

I suggest you reread the [Django documentation on templates and inheritance](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/topics/templates/).